# Match UTF-8 phrase inside string with preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i'm triyin to match some phrase inside a string as a word (stristr doesn't work beacause i dont want results that contain the "word")

I use this code:

```
function striword($string, $word) {
    return preg_match("/(?:[[:space:]]|^)" . $word . "(?:[^\w]|$)/i", $string);
}
```

But when I try to match a string like "this is a string" it doesn't work as expected :(

Example:

```
//Phrase to match: "soda and beer"

striword($string, "soda and beer");

String 1: "I like soda and beer" MATCH: TRUE
String 2: "I like soda and beerbum" MATCH: FALSE
String 3: "I like soda and beer, it's nice!" MATCH: TRUE
```

Comment: Why do you use `[[:space:]]` in one place and `[^\w]` in the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

Either use word boundary anchors (useful if you're dealing with actual, alphanumeric words):

```
preg_match("/\b" . $word . "\b/i", $string);
```

Or use spaces as separators:

```
preg_match("/(?:^|\s)" . $word . "(?:\s|$)/i", $string);
```

If you're using Unicode strings and want to match Unicode words, don't forget the `/u` modifier.

Comment: I'm dealing with alphanumeric words, but they can contain spaces, hypens, utf characters...

Comment: They're not alphanumeric then. (+1 for perfect answer)